# Does anyone recognise this poem - from my mum (90)?

Tags: identification-request, poetry

> Once upon a summer in the hills by the river
>   Was a deep green forest where the wild things grow.
>   There were paths as ...?....?
>   There were ...?...?...?
>   And a thousand little spaces where the sky looked through
>
> Deep inside the forest where the moss was soft as velvet
>   And the ..?..?..?  dusky risky as could be
>   Where the days were full of shadows
>   And the nights were full of darkness
>   Was a deep old hollow tree

Does anyone recognise this poem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from *Honey Bear* (1923) by [Dixie Willson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixie_Willson), a narrative poem about “a big black bear” who steals a “cosy, rosy, baby” and takes it away into the forest. The stanzas your mother remembered are:

> Once upon a summer in the hills by the river
>   Was a deep green forest where the wild things grew.
>   There were caves as dark as midnight—there were tangled trees and thickets
>   And a thousand little places where the sky looked through.
>
> Now ’way inside the forest where the path was lost in nothing
>   And the moss was soft as velvet—dusky, rusky as could be,
>   Where the day was full of shadows, and the night was full of darkness
>   And nobody ever found it—was a big old hollow tree!